# Send mail errors and upload error

Tags: php, file-upload

I have created a form, it's working fine, but I have two problems:

1. I am receiving this error message:

> Warning: mail(/var/log/phpmail.log): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in /www1/xxx/Contact_Us.php on line 115.

2. I can't upload files greater than 20KB even if in my code I allow till 2 MB and on the php.ini `upload_max_filesize` is 8MB and `post_max_size`is 8MB.

So please can anyone help me with these two problems?

```
<?php
//set tiem zone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
// Show errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// define Errors variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $humanErr = $fileErr = $result = $result2 =  "" ;

// when we press submit do the following
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// define contact form variables
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$human = $_POST['human'];

// define Checks variables
$check1 = $check2 = $check3  = $check4  = "";


// Let's do some checks 
// Checking the First Name
if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
    $fnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
      $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
        $check1 = 1;
    }
}
// Checking the Last Name   
if(empty($_POST["lname"])){
    $lnameErr = "Name is Required";
}else{
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
      $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }else{
        $check2 = 1;
    }
}
//Checking the Email Adress
if(empty($_POST["email"])){
    $emailErr = "Email is Required";
}else{
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }else{
        $check3 = 1;
    }
}
//Checking the Anti-Spam Question
if(empty($_POST["human"])){
    $humanErr = "Please Enter the Answer";
}else{
    if ($human != 4){
        $humanErr = "Please check your answer";
    }else{
        $check4 = 1;
    }
}

// checking the attachment
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx");

    $files = array();
    foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
        $file_name = $file['name']; 
        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $file['type'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];

        if($file_size > 2000000){
        $fileErr = "Max allowed size is 2 MB";
        } else {
                if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
                $fileErr = "File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed";    
                }else{
                    array_push($files,$file);}

               }
    }


// define email variables
$to = 'email@domain.com';
$from = "Job Application"; 
$subject = 'Job Application';
$message = 'From: '.$fname .$lname."\r\n".
           'E-mail: '.$email."\r\n".
           'Telephone: '.$tel."\r\n".
           'Designation: '.$design."\r\n".
           'Country Appled From: '.$country."\r\n".
           'Message: '.$comment."\r\n"."\r\n";
$headers = "From: $from";   
// boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments

    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $files[$x]['name'];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }   


// Emailing the Contents if all Checks are correct  
if($check1 && $check2 && $check3 && $check4  == 1){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $result =  "Message Sent Sucessfully";
}else{
    $result2 = "Message Can't be sent";
}
} }
 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: How many files are you trying to upload during one submit? If all of them add up to more than 8M then that will blow your `post_max_size`! ___NOTE___ `post_max_size` should be larger than `upload_max_filesize` so you leave room for normal inputs as well

Comment: Which is line 15 of Contact_Us.php?

Comment: @ RiggsFolly i uploaded only one file with size 200 kb but it didn't accept it.... u helped me last time and solved my problem wish u help me this time also

Comment: @ thebluefox  line 115 is the mail() function line

Comment: @ RiggsFolly  @ thebluefox  i think its about the php code configuration but i really don't know how to adjust that

Comment: ___Guess___ The Warning makes me think you have set `mail.log` in your `php.ini` but you have set it to a place that the server does not have permissions to access

Comment: ___File Size Issue___ Test the `$_FILES['fieldname']['error']` this often give you a big clue as to what is going wrong when uploading files [here is the manual page for error code descriptions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: i have created a folders /var/log/phpmail.log and i gave 777 permissions but still same error and that gonna drive me crazy

Comment: and the problem that i tried it on local webhost "Wampserver" and its working great with no errors at all

Comment: @ RiggsFolly at least can u tell me how to create this directory and make server can read it ??